# How do I find $\gamma$ from $100^{\gamma} = \frac{1}{2} (144^{\gamma} + 64 ^{\gamma})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How do I find $\gamma$ such that $100^{\gamma} = \frac{1}{2} (144^{\gamma} + 64 ^{\gamma})$?

I know the solution is $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}$.

I have tried:

- Unpacking the equation into products of prime numbers and eyeballing a common base.
- Juggling the terms around with no particular outcome in mind to see if I recognized another form of the expression.
- Applying log to both sides.
- Substituting $3^2+4^2=5^2$ for the $5^2$ factor in $100^{\gamma}$.

Comment: $\gamma=0$ also works.

Comment: and $$\gamma=\frac{1}{2}$$ also works

Comment: There are also complex solutions, e.g. approximately $1.9990773868712900980+17.775048467812101885 i$.

Comment: There's not going to be an algebraic solution to this. But another way to spot the $\gamma=1/2$ solution is to note that each term is a perfect square, so it's equivalent to $10^{2\gamma}=\frac12(12^{2\gamma}+8^{2\gamma})$ which has an obvious solution when the exponents are all 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea: Simplify first (I will use $x$)

\begin{align}
100^x &= \frac{1}{2}*(144^x+64^x)\\
2 &= \frac{144^x + 64^x}{100^x}\\
2 &= \left( \frac{144}{100} \right) ^x + \left( \frac{64}{100} \right) ^x\\
2 &= \left( \frac{36}{25} \right) ^x + \left( \frac{16}{25} \right) ^x\\
\end{align}

Here we look for the easiest ways to solve. Noticing that both terms on the right (like @semiclassical said) are perfect squares would result in rational terms. This gives us the obvious $x = 0, \frac{1}{2}$

Finding the derivative of $f(x) = (\frac{36}{25})^x + (\frac{16}{25})^x $,

$$f'(x) = \left( \frac{36}{25} \right) ^x*\ln \left( \frac{36}{25} \right) +  \left( \frac{16}{25} \right) ^x\ln \left( \frac{16}{25} \right)$$

Here, we notice that there is only one negative term in this, $\ln(16/25)$. Therefore, we can extrapolate that there will only be one zero.

Looking at the limit of $f(x)$, we see that it approaches $\infty$ on both sides, and we can pretty much intuitively see that it is strictly increasing when $x \gt$ critical point and strictly decreasing when $x \lt$ critical point.

Therefore, assuming that the critical point/minimum is below $y=2$, there can be a maximum of two solutions. We have found both of them, so we are done.